# Работа с массивом js

Tags: javascript

Есть массив из n элементов. Надо посчитать суммы всех комбинаций из ***k*** элементов этого массива.

Допустим есть массив

`[0 , 1 , 2 ,3 , 4]`

и к примеру надо посчитать суммы из **3x** элементов этого массива -

`[0,1,2] , [0,1,3] , [0,1,4]`

и так далее и найти наибольшую из них. Как это оформить на языке js.

Comment: найти k максимальных значений и взять их сумму. в целом можно для этих целей отсортировать массив (что для решения избыточно, конечно)

Answer (score 2):

максимальная сумма достигается путем суммирования максимальных элементов. Следовательно, надо либо отсортировать массив и взять k-элемнтов  (первых или последних в зависимости от порядка сортировки) и сложить их, либо что будет более эффективно на больших массивах - не сортировать, а просто найти k-максимумов.

```js
const data = [1,-1,2,3,0,5],
      k = 3;


let result = data.sort().slice(-k).reduce((acc,v) => acc+v, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ , но мне необходим именно процесс суммирования всех комбинаций из 3 элементов

Comment: @stas у вас написано "найти наибольшую сумму".

Comment: Не корректно поставил вопрос

Comment: [тогда выбирайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)